# phmagick class not found on laravel 4

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-4

After installing phmagick using composer I'm getting a class not found error. I think it's because of how the Action classes are being loaded, but is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in `vendor/francodacosta/phmagick/docs/index.html` for actual documentation about phMagick.  Here's one of the examples which works for me...

```
$phMagick = new \phMagick\Core\Runner();
$action = new \phMagick\Action\Convert($this->originalFile, $this->newFile);

// optimize the image
$action->optimize();

// sets image quality
$action->quality(70);

// execute the convert action
$phMagick->run($action);
```